# seeking clarification on how to integrate tesseract in a VC2010 C program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, build, tesseract

This question is related to this: (I apologize I don't know how to post it as a follow-up qn):
[How can i use tesseract ocr(or any other free ocr) in small c++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079635/how-can-i-use-tesseract-ocror-any-other-free-ocr-in-small-c-project)

The latest response from user sventech says :
This is out of date. All that is now required is libtesseract. The standard code includes support for VS2008 and 2010 is trivial with the instructions. – sventech Sep 19 at 14:42

I would like to find out if you are saying that one does not have to do those steps since there is a an easier way to just use the library without having to build it ? Since I am not very experienced on buidling the open source libraries I would like to surely avoid it if possible. What is the easiest way to integrate tesseract function calls into a C prorgram (VS2010) ?  Thanks much, JV Iyer.

Comment: what surprise me is that you are using VS for programming in C, it's well know the fact that VS has a really bad support for C.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://ayoungprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/11/tutorial-installing-tesseract-ocr-30202.html?showComment=1352898224531#c2791256718078577473) link wold be useful.
If you use VS2010 you have to find directories in your project properties by right-click/properties.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Normally you need only the [Win32-libs](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-3.02.02-win32-lib-include-dirs.zip)

De-zip it, you will have these two folders :
D:\tesseract-3.02.02\lib
D:\tesseract-3.02.02\include

2 - But you will need also (for debug) liblept168.dll, liblept168.lib that you will find by installing [Tesseract setup](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe)

Copy these files in D:\tesseract-3.02.02\lib

Add also this folder to your path.

3- In your vc2010 project, add in the Project Properties :

- C/C++ -> Other includes folder : D:\tesseract-3.02.02\include
- Linker -> General : D:\tesseract-3.02.02\lib
- Linker -> Dependencies -> input : libtesseract302.lib(Debug & Release)

Note :
The libtesseract302d.lib is build for vc2008, that why you have c0150002 error when you use it. Good way should to build from the source on vc2010 ...