# How to implement Tesseract to run with project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010 and wish to use OCR. I came across many "tutorials" for Tesseract but sadly, all I got was a headache and wasted time.

In my project I have an image stored as a **Mat**. One solution to my problem is to save this Mat as an image (image.jpg for example) and then call Tesseract executable file like this:

```
system("tesseract.exe image.jpg out");
```

Which gets me an output *out.txt* and then I call

```
infile.open ("out.txt");
```

to read the output from Tesseract.

It is all good and works like a chair but it is not an optimal solution. In my project I am processing a video so *save/call .exe/write/read* at 10+ FPS is not what I am really looking for. I want to implement Tesseract to existing code so to be able to pass a Mat as an argument and immediately get a result as a String.

Do you know any good tutorial(pref. step-by-step) to implement Tesseract OCR with Visual Studio 2010? Or your own solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, I figured it out but it works for **Release** and **Win32** configuration only (No debug or x64). There are many linking errors under Debug configuration.

So,

**1.** First of all, download prepared library folder(Tesseract + Leptonica) here:

[Mirror 1(Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B52jOwoWvqGyX0U3THFHZEJkMlk/edit?usp=sharing)

[Mirror 2(MediaFire)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/dhhejbcjg5ecd3n/tesseract.zip)

---

**2.** Extract `tesseract.zip` to `C:\`

---

**3.** In Visual Studio, go under `C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`

Insert `C:\tesseract\include`

---

**4.** Under `Linker > General > Additional Library Directories`

Insert `C:\tesseract\lib`

---

**5.** Under `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`

Add:

```
liblept168.lib
libtesseract302.lib
```

---

Sample code should look like this:

```
#include <tesseract\baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica\allheaders.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
    api.Init("", "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    api.SetPageSegMode(static_cast<tesseract::PageSegMode>(7));
    api.SetOutputName("out");

    cout<<"File name:";
    char image[256];
    cin>>image;
    PIX   *pixs = pixRead(image);

    STRING text_out;
    api.ProcessPages(image, NULL, 0, &text_out);

    cout<<text_out.string();

    system("pause");
}
```

For interaction with OpenCV and **Mat** type images look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115368/converting-cvmat-for-tesseract)

Comment: I said language data path like that it worked.
api.Init("C:\\tessdata", "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);

Comment: I cant find folder that "tessdata" ?? Should I create it orit must be in folder @İsmailKocacan

Comment: I download folder your link but it did not tessdata?? @OpenMinded

Comment: Custom "tessdata" language folder was used by user @İsmailKocacan so ask him.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a lot since the last reply but it may be help to others;

1. I think you must also add "liblept168.lib" and "liblept168d.lib" to Additional Dependencies
2. Add "liblept168.dll" and "liblept168d.dll" to the destination of your exe.
3. Add #include  to your code.

(This answer must be a comment to Bruce's answer. Sorry for confusion. )

Comment: When you say "add #include to your code", what exactly must be included?

Comment: you should add:
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the library through the API.

Most probably:

- start by downlaoding the libs ( https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-3.02.02-win32-lib-include-dirs.zip&can=2&q= ). They're compiled with Visual 2008 but it should be enough
- Use the API directly (example, look at an open source project using it: https://code.google.com/p/qtesseract/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftessdata ) and read the links from this answer : [How can i use tesseract ocr(or any other free ocr) in small c++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079635/how-can-i-use-tesseract-ocror-any-other-free-ocr-in-small-c-project)

Comment: Downloaded the libs. In _C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories:_ Added _\include_ folder. In _Linker>General>Additional Library Directories:_ Added _\lib_ folder. In _Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies:_ Added _libtesseract302.lib_ and _libtesseract302d.lib_. Wrote a simple program and can't build because of linking errors for every method called on object. For example: `Error 9 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: char * __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetUTF8Text(void)" (?GetUTF8Text@TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAAPEADXZ) referenced in function main`. What am I missing?

Comment: Good news : compilation step is working. Bad news, linking step is failing. It looks like it's not finding the correct library for linking. I would advise to use libtesseract302.lib in release and libtesseract302d.lib in debug. You can go to ConfigurationPropertis / Linked / command line in your visual project to make sure the command line is pointing to correct location

Comment: Been using x64 configuration because of OpenCV...so I switched to x86. No more Tesseract linking errors. Now I have similar linking errors but with OpenCV functions. So I threw away OpenCV and tried to build Tesseract only to see if it works. Switched imread(OpenCV) for pixRead(Leptonica?). Apparently, it does not recognize this function pixRead. I think I need leptonica headers? allheaders.h or what? I slowly give up on everything :-/