# How to use tessdata in opencv?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, tesseract

I have created a Tesseract based OCR using C# but it is not running on other computers. So I was thinking if it's possible to use Tesseract trained data in OpenCV, or at least converting the trained data to an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Tesseract data with OpenCV.

**C#**

Check **EmguCV** library and example code for OCR (Emgu.CV.Example folder) where Tesseract is called and so you can specify a prefix for your trained data.

**C++**

See answer [How to implement Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141716/999536)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.I already created my ocr in C# and its running fine on my system but giving error on other systems " An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.".So I was thinking of using tesseract trained data in c++ using opencv but without using tesseract because at the time tesseract loads application throws an error.