# How to configure and build Tesseract OCR C++ using Visual Studio 2015 x64 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to run the [VS2015_Tesseract](https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract) example in Tesseract OCR Library.

I always get the following error when I try to open the file:

> Could not find a part of the path

Currently I am working with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 (64 bit).

Please provide the full information on how I can configure the Tesseract OCR C++ library on **Visual Studio 2015 Windows 10 (64 bit)**.

You also can provide any reference tutorial links.

Comment: You can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180824/how-to-implement-tesseract-to-run-with-project-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have to download the [vs2015_Tesseract](https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract/) or simply run the following git command in working directory:

   `git clone https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract.git`
2. Run the `build_tesseract.bat` file.
3. Activate `tesseract` as the startup project.

Comment: Best solution for windows since tesseract requires a lot 3rd party libs. really great link