# error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct tagBLOB BLOB' in c++ when I use tesseract engine

Tags: c++, codeblocks, tesseract

I am using tesseract engine with openCV3.0. 
When I use:

```
 #include <tesseract\baseapi.h>
```

It shows:

> x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -std=c++11 -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT -DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT -IC:\tesseract\tesseract\include -IC:\tesseract\tesseract\include\leptonica -IC:\tesseract\tesseract\include\tesseract -c F:\freelancer\RajivCK\test\ocrtest2\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
>   In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/combaseapi.h:153:0,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/objbase.h:14,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/ole2.h:17,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wtypes.h:12,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winscard.h:10,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:97,
>                    from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\host.h:25,
>                    from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\tesscallback.h:22,
>                    from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\baseapi.h:31,
>                    from F:\freelancer\RajivCK\test\ocrtest2\main.cpp:1:
>   C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wtypesbase.h:385:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct tagBLOB BLOB'
>    } BLOB;
>      ^
>   In file included from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\baseapi.h:27:0,
>                    from F:\freelancer\RajivCK\test\ocrtest2\main.cpp:1:
>   C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\platform.h:30:3: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _BLOB BLOB'
>    } BLOB, *LPBLOB;
>      ^
>   In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/combaseapi.h:153:0,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/objbase.h:14,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/ole2.h:17,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wtypes.h:12,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winscard.h:10,
>                    from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:97,
>                    from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\host.h:25,
>                    from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\tesscallback.h:22,
>                    from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\baseapi.h:31,
>                    from F:\freelancer\RajivCK\test\ocrtest2\main.cpp:1:
>   C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wtypesbase.h:386:25: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct tagBLOB* LPBLOB'
>    typedef struct tagBLOB *LPBLOB;
>                            ^
>   In file included from C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\baseapi.h:27:0,
>                    from F:\freelancer\RajivCK\test\ocrtest2\main.cpp:1:
>   C:\tesseract\tesseract\include/tesseract\platform.h:30:10: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _BLOB* LPBLOB'
>    } BLOB, *LPBLOB;
>   '

The guide for tesseract engine was used from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141716/6847152).

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the failing code, and then edit your question to show it to us? And when you do that, also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output (including any possible informational notes).

Comment: This error tells us you have two declarations with the same name. However,  we can't tell more, due to the lack of information posted on the question. You might check your include lists, to see if they conflict with each other...

Comment: I followed the example in the above link. The above question is edited for complete error.

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong binaries which were not prebuilt for my OS