# tesseract initialization failure

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract into VS2010 project to get some text from an image.

I am using the following code:

```
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
    if(0 != api.Init(NULL, _T("eng"), tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT))
    {
        m_sError.Format(_T("tesseract initialize error"));
        return;
    }
    api.SetPageSegMode(static_cast<tesseract::PageSegMode>(7));
    PIX* pixs = pixRead(sFileName);
    STRING txtout;
    if(! api.ProcessPages(sFileName, NULL, 0, &txtout))
    {
        m_sError.Format(_T("tesseract process error"));
        return;
    }
```

but I always get error at **api.init** method ...

I have taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180824/how-to-implement-tesseract-to-run-with-project-in-visual-studio-2010) the sample code, and the compiled tesseract library. I have applied all specification from that post, and I have tried this even on Release, with the same result.

Also, I have tried to compile the tesseract library on my own, but I have VS2010 only. [Here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) is saying that I need VS2015 or above, and I have found [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases) a VS2010 tesseract binaries, but even here I have met errors at compile time:

*fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'allheaders.h': No such file or directory*

Why I get Init error ? If there something wrong with my library, can you give me some compiled tesseract library in order to use it in my VS2010 project ? Can you help a little bit ?

Comment: When I had tried to create a solution from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract I get from CMake the following message: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Leptonica" ... can you lead me into using tesseract inside of MFC VS2010 project ?

Comment: I have compiled everything with VS2017, and I get rid of any error ... but when I have tried the code from above, I get the same error on api.Init method ... does anybody tried this example ?